# Using Ruby to send SMSs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sms, sms-gateway

I'm trying to code for an sms server using the following tutorial.

http://lukeredpath.co.uk/blog/sending-sms-messages-from-your-rails-application.html

Here they advice us to use clickatell but i have a gateway that i can use which i would like to use. However i wouldn't know how to write the bits of code that says require clickatell or sudo gem install clickatell. I'm new to ruby and rails hence any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

In `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'clickatell`
```

Then run `bundle install`.

Comment: Im not using clickatell. Im using another gateway? Thats where my doubt lies.

Comment: Then it's a different API and the gem won't help you. You need your gateway's API.

Comment: Hey you've asked a couple of questions on this. How urgent? Which gateway? Do they have API docs? If they don't have a gem, how much would you pay for someone to write one (on the condition it's open-source)?

Comment: lol. Unfortunately i cant enclose details of the gateway, They do have an api. Hmmmph. As for paying someone to write a gem. Well i dont have a problem paying but this was a uni project given for me to write hence i dont want to cheat :D

Comment: Haha good luck then. 1 or 2 lines using `Net::HTTP` and you'll have a very hacky SMS sender. SMS is a best-effort protocol after all... and it doesn't specify how much effort is one's best!